# How to append input data attribute to a button securely with Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the data from an `input` of the type number field and set its value to the `data-quantity` attribute on a button in the same parent div. I understand how to get the value from the Quantity field but I am not sure how to append it to the `data-attribute` of the button. This will be used for adding item into cart, so there will be more than 1 item.

Here's my code and what I tried:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 m6">
        <input class="qtyBox" type="number" name="productQty" value="1" min="1" max="3">
    </div>
    <div class="col s12 m6">
        <a data-shop="<?= $product['s_id'] ?>" data-prod="<?= $product['product_id']  ?>" data-quantity="3" class="modal-trigger waves-effect btn-small orange darken-2 text-normal action-btn right addToCart">Add to Cart</a>
    </div>
</div>


$('.qtyBox').on('change', function({
    $(this).next('a').attr('data-quantity', $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: What doesn't work here?

Comment: `next()` only works on siblings.  The input and link are not siblings.  Please refer to the duplicate about adjusting your logic to use a shared parent to find the contextual elements.

Comment: `$(this).closest(".row").find('a').attr('data-quantity', $(this).val());`